# Minecraft servers running on single host, Issues with Systemd

Tags: server, java, systemd, proxy, minecraft

I have a minecraft server running off a VM & I cannot get systemd to start and run them. I did, but it stopped working after I was messing with the config and I've not been able to restore it.

Its one host, Its got a bungeecord proxy and 3 other worlds all running in seperate instances. Here's the exact tutorial I followed and I've basically copied this line by line:
https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-minecraft-server-setup

I have a directory structure where /opt is the parent and has /bungeecord /hub /survival /creative inside and within those folders, all have a minecraft_server.jar file in them. This does mean that all the servers run at the same ram size since in the systemd script I have not found a way to independantly run them, but cross that bridge when we get to it.

When I do

```
sudo systemctl status minecraft@hub
```

It shows active no problem, and as mentioned before I was able to restart and stop if needed and was able to connect to them no problem. When I go onto the game now and connect, I get connection refused.

I know its systemd and not my server config as I am able to run the servers if I stop the service and start the proxy and the hub for example like so:

/opt/bungeecord

```
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

/opt/hub

```
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar
```

I would then get 2 consoles that show me the world loading and I am able to connect if I just refresh the server list in game. Simply restarting the VM or doing a systemd command no longer seems to run the server anymore, despite the status of them being enabled. This isn't ny  first server but it is my first attempt at setting up my own at home instead of using an external company.

Any help would be amazing, otherwise I will just be forced to run them in screen via the commands above.

Comment: Ah man I hate myself, after configuring, I didn't do a chown back to the username Minecraft.